# Wix 3.6: Conditionally trigger "RemoveExistingProducts"

Tags: wix, upgrade, wix3.6

I crawled the web but found no solution or I just got not the clue.

I need to conditionally perform the `RemoveExistingProducts` action in my setup. I want my setup to uninstall all existing products by default, like this:

```
<MajorUpgrade AllowDowngrades="no" DowngradeErrorMessage="No downgrades allowed" />
```

This works fine. But when the user deselects a checkbox in my UI I want the installer NOT to uninstall previous product version. So I tried something like this:

```
    <Property Id="PREVIOUSVERSIONSINSTALLED" Secure="yes" />

    <Upgrade Id="3E700BA7-CAF8-4C49-A53A-70F70DE0C8D6">
        <UpgradeVersion
             Minimum="1.0.0.0" Maximum="99.0.0.0"
             Property="PREVIOUSVERSIONSINSTALLED"
             IncludeMinimum="yes" IncludeMaximum="no" OnlyDetect="myVar" />
    </Upgrade>

    <Property Id="myVar" Value="no" />
```

hoping, that I can set the `myVar`, but this is illegal.

Has anybody an idea how to solve my problem?

The reason is, that we want to allow the users - at their own risk - to have more than one version of our product installed - this is a request by our customer.

Answer (score 0):

I think, in the default sequence, `RemoveExistingProducts` is run before the UI.

You could try rewiring the `RemoveExistingProducts` action to be after `InstallFinalize` and trigger it with a condition:

```
<RemoveExistingProducts After="InstallFinalize">
    NOT CHECKBOX
</RemoveExistingProducts>
```

Not sure how this would fare in your case.

You could also try running a custom action when you exit the dialog with your checkbox to manually uninstall the product. Maybe you could even force the launch of `RemoveExistingProducts` in said custom action.

One last solution would be to make a separate uninstaller that prompts the user to uninstall the product or not and follow up with the actual installer.